# Reusing compiled regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, perl

I have a program in Perl that uses a regular expression to store supported file extensions. It reuses this regex through the code. Each file extension has a description since the regular expression has the 'x' flag. I cannot figure out how to port this to python (2.7).

#### The original Perl

```perl
use strict;

my @files = ('foo.abc','foo.ABC','foo.mi','foo.txt','foo.ma','foo.iff','foo.avi');

my $exts = qr/abc|mi|avi|ma|iff|tga/;

foreach my $f (sort @files) {
    if ($f =~ m/^([^.]+\.$exts)/) {
        print "file matches: $f\n";
    } 
    else {
        print "file does not match: $f\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
file does not match: foo.ABC
file matches: foo.abc
file matches: foo.avi
file matches: foo.iff
file matches: foo.ma
file matches: foo.mi
file does not match: foo.txt
```

This works just as well when I add whitespace with the `/x` modifier

```perl
$exts = qr/
    abc  (?# alembic )
    |mi  (?# mentalray )
    |avi (?# windows video )
    |ma  (?# maya ascii )
    |iff (?# amiga bitmap )
    |tga (?# targa bitmap )
/ix;

foreach my $f (sort @files) {

    if ( $f =~ m/^([^.]+\.$exts )/ ) {
        print "file matches: $f\n";
    }
    else {
        print "file does not match: $f\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
file matches: foo.ABC
file matches: foo.abc
file matches: foo.avi
file matches: foo.iff
file matches: foo.ma
file matches: foo.mi
file does not match: foo.txt
```

Python supports compiled regular expressions, and you can use them as components of other regular expressions

#### Python

```python
import re

files = [ 'foo.abc','foo.ABC','foo.mi','foo.txt','foo.ma','foo.iff','foo.avi' ]

exts = re.compile(r'(?:abc|mi|avi|ma|iff|tga)')

for f in sorted(files):
    m = re.search(r'^([^.]+\.{EXTS})'.format(EXTS=exts.pattern),f)
    if m:
        print 'file matches: {0}'.format(f)
    else:
        print 'file does not match: {0}'.format(f)
```

#### output

```
file does not match: foo.ABC
file matches: foo.abc
file matches: foo.avi
file matches: foo.iff
file matches: foo.ma
file matches: foo.mi
file does not match: foo.txt
'''
```

But as soon as I use `re.VERBOSE`, the regex fails

```python
exts = re.compile(r'''(?:
                     abc   # alembic
                    |mi    # mentalray
                    |avi   # windows video
                    |ma    # maya ascii
                    |iff   # amiga bitmap
                    |tga   # targa bitmap
                    )''', re.IGNORECASE + re.VERBOSE)

for f in sorted(files):
    m = re.search(r'^([^.]+\.{EXTS})'.format(EXTS=exts.pattern),f)
    if m:
        print 'file matches: {0}'.format(f)
    else:
        print 'file does not match: {0}'.format(f)
```

#### output

```
file does not match: foo.ABC
file does not match: foo.abc
file does not match: foo.avi
file does not match: foo.iff
file does not match: foo.ma
file does not match: foo.mi
file does not match: foo.txt
```

My actual code has more than 50 extensions, with comments about what they are, so I would really like to support this.

I've searched all the "nested regular expression" posts I could find, but all of them are string hacks. No *actual* regular expression nesting that I can find.

Can Python do this?

Comment: no, it can't. However you should always be able to use `'(?:' + re_string + ')'` as a string hack.

Comment: Note that there's no need for `(?# ... )` to add comments when you're using the `/x` modifier: you can just use bare Perl comments `#...`. The same rules apply in Python, and there should be no difference between the two patterns.

Comment: **Note**: the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) clearly says that the `x` flag (i.e. `re.VERBOSE`) **cannot** be put mid pattern. It must be the first thing in the pattern (eventually preceded by *whitespace*). Otherwise the results are undefined. So yours is a hack that the documentation clearly states it doesn't have to work, and it may just work for some patterns or some specific versions of python and fail in others.  You are right tough regarding the `(?i)` flag.

Comment: I've deleted your answer from the question. Questions should **not** contain answers. If you have an answer *post it as such*, it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this completely wrong. First of all the `.pattern` attribute is just **a string**. So it's 100% useless calling `re.compile` and then extracting the initial string used to obtain the regex object to pass to `re.search`:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'''(
...     verbose #lol
...     | pattern  #rofl
... )
... ''', re.VERBOSE)
>>> regex.match('verbose')  # finds the match!
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='verbose'>
>>> re.search(regex.pattern, 'verbose')  # does not find the match!
>>>
```

As you can see the `pattern` attribute is just the **initial** string used to build the regex object:

```
>>> regex.pattern
'(\n    verbose #lol\n    | pattern  #rofl\n)\n'
>>> type(regex.pattern)
<class 'str'>
```

So by passing this into `re.search` you make `re.search` *recompile* it, and since `re.search` doesn't have the `re.VERBOSE` flag it compiles it with a different meaning:

```
>>> re.search(regex.pattern, 'verbose', re.VERBOSE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='verbose'>
```

Also, I'd do this instead:

```
exts = [
    'abc',   # extension abc blah blah
    'cde',   # extension cde blah blah
]
exts_pattern = '(?:{})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(extension) for extension in exts))

regex = re.compile(r'^([^.]+\.{}'.format(exts_pattern), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or similar. I.e. you keep the various extensions as a `list` and put whatever python comments you want, and when you build the regex object using `compile` you iterate over those. This makes adding an extension easier, and also it's probably useful to have such list anyways.

---

And to answer your final question: no python `re` module does not support "regex nesting" in any way. You must provide a *string* pattern which gets compiled into a regex object.

Comment: This is pretty much the advice that I would give in the Perl domain, so yes. Spot on. There is a difference with Perl that a compiled regex pattern stringifies to include enclosing non-capturing parentheses which also sets the appropriate options. For instance, `perl -e 'print qr/a b c/x'` produces `(?^x:a b c)`, which is a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` where the `^` sets all the default (read "backward-compatible") flags, while `x` enables the equivalent to the `VERBOSE` option. So it is in it's own little regex-cosm, and would perform properly even if it were inserted into another regex.

Comment: The subtle difference - but important difference - is that perl maintains the flags for the compiled regex when it stringifies it as @Borodin points out. See `perl -e 'print qr/a b c/xi'` preserves the case-insensitive 'i' option. In @Bakuriu's final line the `re.IGNORECASE` applies to the entire regex, not just the extensions as in the Perl example. I guess I'm saying the same thing @Borodin said, but this is a very frustrating reality.

Comment: I should also comment that the list version proposed does not support several extensions on the full list, like `|aiff?`, `|jpe?g`, `|pict?`, and `|tiff?`.

Comment: @whereisalext It does. Just add more extensions: `exts = ['aiff', 'aif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ...]`. Yes, a bit longer but the finaly compiled regex should be equivalent. AFAIK there is simply no way to have only part of the expression have a flag, so you'll have to deal with it: either the whole regex is case insensitive/verbose, or it is not. Period.

Comment: The expression can have a flag. See my update at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: @whereisalext You are *half* right. Some flags can be put wherever you want **but** the `x` flag (i.e. `re.VERBOSE`) **cannot** and the documentation states so. So the OP could put the `(?i)` flag mid pattern, but there is no way to mix verbose and non-verbose regexes.

Answer (score 1):

It is a myth that Perl will interpolate one compiled regular expression into another. If you write this

```
my $exts = qr/ abc | mi | avi | ma | iff | tga /x;

if ( $f =~ /^([^.]+\.$exts)/ ) {
    ...
}
```

then within `$f =~ /^([^.]+\.$exts)/`, the contents of the regex pattern is evaluated in a *double-quote context*. That means Perl will *stringify* `$exts` to something like `(?^x: abc | mi | avi | ma | iff | tga )` (the exact result depends on what Perl pragma are in place) and *interpolate* that string before compiling the pattern

So the regex match is actually doing this

```
$f =~ /^([^.]+\.(?^x: abc | mi | avi | ma | iff | tga ))/
```

which is clearly correct, because the `/x` modifier is enabled within the expression

The difference from Python is ***only*** that Python is not as careful about what an `re` object returns by its `pattern` or `__str__` methods, so they can't be injected as substrings into other patterns

As far as I know, the `pattern` method just returns the original regex string that was compiled to create the object. That makes it much like using C `#define` symbols: you must be very careful with parentheses, either in the definition of the original or in its invocation

Comment: Does perl support flags mid pattern? In python you **cannot** have flags applied to just a piece of the pattern, so either the whole regex is case insensitive, or it is not. You cannot have the first part case sensitive and the last part case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can! In the Python documentation on re I found that you can specify any re flag in the expression itself - similar to how Perl prints the re flag inline. By adding the flag to the string hack you can achieve the result:

```
exts = '''(?ix)(?:
                   abc   # alembic
                  |mi    # mentalray
                  |avi   # windows video
                  |ma    # maya ascii
                  |iff   # amiga bitmap
                  |tga   # targa bitmap
               )'''

for f in sorted(files):
   m = re.search(r'^([^.]+\.{EXTS})'.format(EXTS=exts),f)
   if m:
      print 'file matches: {0}'.format(f)
   else:
      print 'file does not match: {0}'.format(f)
```

The `(?ix)` is non-grouping, but sets the re.IGNORECASE and re.VERBOSE.